# Почему ссылки ведут на старый домен?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, drupal, drupal7

После переноса сайта (Drupal7) на другой домен, сайт работает, но все ссылки ведут на старый домен. в файле sites.php указал строчку нового домена и старого. Пути относительные указаны. В чем может быть проблема?

Вот сам сайт: specpricep.saytum.ru

Comment: В том что они где-то хранятся (в БД, например) в полном виде

Answer (score 1):

Выгрузить базу в SQL. В любом текстовом редакторе сделать замену по всему файлу старого домена на новый. Загрузить БД.

Comment: Тогда сайт перестает работать

Comment: @VyacheslavDmitrievich с чего это вдруг он перестанет работать? Все ссылки будут заменены на новый домен.